# Bash / CentOS 7 trying to automatically install and setup PostgreSQL but fail

Tags: centos, bash, postgresql

Im trying to install and setup PostgreSQL on CentOS 7 automatically using a bash script, im very very new to this and i was hoping i could get some help.

So, I have the following so far;

```
# Install PostgreSQL ( 9.6 )
curl -O https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install postgresql96-server.x86_64 postgresql96-contrib.x86_64 postgresql96-devel.x86_64

# Init Postgresql
sudo /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
sudo systemctl enable postgresql-9.6
sudo systemctl start postgresql-9.6

# Configure remote access
sudo sed -i "s/#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/g" /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf
echo "host    all             all             10.0.2.2/32               md5" | sudo tee -a /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf

# Configure PostgreSQL user / database
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE ROLE myboxname LOGIN UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret' SUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;"
sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/createdb --echo --owner=myboxname myboxname
```

Everything works perfect except for when it comes to the last 2 lines.

When i run the first line i get the following output;

```
could not change directory to "/home/username": Permission denied
CREATE ROLE
```

and when i run the second command, i get this;

```
could not change directory to "/home/username": Permission denied
CREATE DATABASE myboxname OWNER myboxname;
```

Then when i try and run `psql` i get the following;

```
psql: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

Im so confused.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are pointing to two problems. First, postgres user does not have permission to /home/username. This is happening in the CentOS/Linux level. And the second error is that postgres cannot find role "username". So first you need see if the postgres user is set right. Do just a sudo manually to check:

```
cd ~postgres
sudo -u postgres -i
```

Hopefully no error here. Then you need to create the role. I would suggest to do it manually (outside the script first) to check everything is working ok or not:

```
root# sudo -u postgres -i psql
psql (9.3.20)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create user username;
CREATE ROLE
```

If this works then you can automate the process via the script. You can run `drop user username` to get rid of the user if you want re-create it. 
Hope this helps.